# In groovy pipeline, how to add pattern in switch case?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I m a beginner, trying to use the switch case in the groovy pipeline.
I have defined parameter

1. ENV (choice parameter) with values test1,test2,test3,prod1,prod2,prod3
2. DISPLAY ( Active reactive parameter) with Referenced parameters as ENV

switch("$ENV") {
case "test*":
return ['True']
break
case "prod*":
return ['False']
break
default:
return ['Error in env selection']
break
}

When i give the test1 it works good whereas when i give pattern "test*"  the code output is not as expected.

Kindly help me with the solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the regex pattern matching, see below the solution.
However, using a switch is quite old habit, is kept in the language only because of backward compatibility. Probably in a modern Groovy, you will never see a switch. I added a second solution, how I would solve this.

```
ENV = "prod1"

// classic solution using swtich
def SelectSwitch(value) {
    switch(value) {
        case ~/test.*/:  return 'True'
        case ~/prod.*/:  return 'False'
        default:         return 'Error in env selection'
    }
}

assert SelectSwitch(ENV) == 'False'

// modern approach using a map
def SelectMap(value) {
    ['test.*': 'True', 'prod.*': 'False' ]
        .find { value ==~ it.key }
        ?.value
        ?: 'Error in env selection'
}

assert SelectMap(ENV) == 'False'
```